# Why is react-native gifted chat returning undefined is not a function?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I have encountered this error when attempting to build a a chat application on react native using gifted chat. Here is my Chat.js code. Whenever I add gifted chat to my application this error appears. I think there is something wrong with gifted chat. I don't know whether the file has become corrupt or something.

Error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function

This error is located at:
    in MessageContainer (created by GiftedChat)
```

Chat.js code:

```js
 // @refresh reset
import { useRoute } from "@react-navigation/native";
import "react-native-get-random-values";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import React, { useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {

  ImageBackground,

} from "react-native";
import { auth, db } from "../firebase";
import GlobalContext from "../context/Context";
import {
  addDoc,
  collection,
  doc,
  onSnapshot,
  setDoc,
  updateDoc,
} from "@firebase/firestore";
import { GiftedChat } from "react-native-gifted-chat";

const randomId = nanoid()

export default function Chat() {
    const [emailHash, setEmailHash] = useState("")
    const [roomHash, setRoomHash] = useState("");
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])

    const {
        theme: { colors },
      } = useContext(GlobalContext);
      const { currentUser } = auth;
      const route = useRoute();
      const room = route.params.room;
      const selectedImage = route.params.image;
      const userB = route.params.user;
    
      const senderUser = currentUser.photoURL
        ? {
            name: currentUser.displayName,
            _id: currentUser.uid,
            avatar: currentUser.photoURL,
          }
        : { name: currentUser.displayName, _id: currentUser.uid };
    
      const roomId = room ? room.id : randomId;
    
      const roomRef = doc(db, "rooms", roomId);
      const roomMessagesRef = collection(db, "rooms", roomId, "messages");
    
      useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          if (!room) {
            const currUserData = {
              displayName: currentUser.displayName,
              email: currentUser.email,
            };
            if (currentUser.photoURL) {
              currUserData.photoURL = currentUser.photoURL;
            }
            const userBData = {
              displayName: userB.contactName || userB.displayName || "",
              email: userB.email,
            };
            if (userB.photoURL) {
              userBData.photoURL = userB.photoURL;
            }
            const roomData = {
              participants: [currUserData, userBData],
              participantsArray: [currentUser.email, userB.email],
            };
            try {
              await setDoc(roomRef, roomData);
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
          }
          const emailHash = `${currentUser.email}:${userB.email}`;
          setRoomHash(emailHash);
        })();
      }, []);


      useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(roomMessagesRef, (querySnapshot) => {
          const messagesFirestore = querySnapshot
            .docChanges()
            .filter(({ type }) => type === "added")
            .map(({ doc }) => {
              const message = doc.data();
              return { ...message, createdAt: message.createdAt.toDate() };
            })
            .sort((a, b) => b.createdAt.getTime() - a.createdAt.getTime());
          appendMessages(messagesFirestore);
        });
        return () => unsubscribe();
      }, []);
    
      const appendMessages = useCallback(
        (messages) => {
          setMessages((previousMessages) =>
            GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, messages)
          );
        },
        [messages]
      );

      async function onSend(messages = []) {
        const writes = messages.map((m) => addDoc(roomMessagesRef, m));
        const lastMessage = messages[messages.length - 1];
        writes.push(updateDoc(roomRef, { lastMessage }));
        await Promise.all(writes);
      }


  return (
    <ImageBackground 
    resizeMode="cover" 
    source={require("../assets/chatbg.png")}
    style={{flex: 1}}
    >
      <GiftedChat

          
      />
    </ImageBackground>
  )
}
```

Can someone pls HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! If you are getting this error it means the package is corrupt and you will need to uninstall it and redownload it.